# What's the benefit of namespaces in PHP?

Tags: php, namespaces

What's the benefit of namespaces in PHP?  I've worked on multiple MVC systems and haven't found much use for them.  I'm reading about them here.... is it a problem of sorts that I've never used them?  Is it the kind of thing that is a good coding standard to always use?

Comment: The same as the benefit of namespaces in any other language. To limit or eliminate ambiguity.

Comment: Avoids collisions in class names

Comment: The supposed use case in PHP is class name aliasing and evading in-identifier grouping for hierarchy and naming conflicts.

Comment: It's a good coding practice for structuring your code, but you don't *always* need to use it (e.g. namespaces are way overkill for a simple script). It's not a problem that you've never used them, because they're only available in a recent version of PHP, so they're not in widespread use yet.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Like any other languages, namespaces allow ambigious names / classes with same name to co-exists while being in two different namespaces.

For example `Table` class can be referring to a table in a persistent database and a HTML table. I can put namespaces to specifically use the exact table that I want, i.e. `\Model\Table` and `\View\Table` respectively.

Comment: Do the namespaces have to have slashes like that, or can you call the namespace whatever you want?

Comment: Most other languages use something like `::` to do namespaces. PHP chose the backslash for various reasons that most everyone except the developers considered insane. The page is down ATM due to a compromise, but their reasoning is normall listed here: http://wiki.php.net/rfc/namespaceseparator

Comment: C# and Java uses `.` for namespaces instead of backslash. PHP cannot use `::` because the operator has already been used to identify static methods.

Comment: @thephpdeveloper: Funnily enough, C# and Java use `.` for namespaces/packages, instance members **and** class members.

Comment: IMHO I think that using `.` would be more consistent, but developers wouldn't be able to figure out if the name is a class name, namespace or reference to class members.

Answer (score 8):

The main advantage of namespaces doesn't usually come from your own application's code, but from **third party libraries**.  Library maintainers can select appropriate namespaces for their own code and ensure that there are no naming conflicts with your own.

Answer (score 6):

Namespace is part of good OOP practices. They are really usefull in big web Application because they help to avoid ambiguity between classes. This is a way to organize your application and makes it more readable.

Answer (score 3):

Imagine you have a huge code base, with thousands of functions, classes and lots of third-party code. And now, two functions happen to have the same name.

That's where namespaces come in - by wrapping your code into namespaces, you can eliminate the possibility of name clashes.

Also, namespaces aid you at structuring your code - everything that belongs to a certain feature or sub-system goes into one namespace.

Answer (score 2):

It helps you to avoid name collisions. For example, if you have two packages, and each has a class named Client (or something general like that), then it would lead to a name collision. Before PHP 5.3 the solution to avoid these collisions was to use class names like this: VendorName_PackageName_Classname

As you can see it's not too nice. But now with PHP 5.3 you can use namespaces to come up with cleaner class names.

Answer (score 0):

It also help your code more flexible and clear.
In comparing, Zend_Database_Adapter_Mysql vs Zend/Database/Adapter/Mysql is equal to avoid ambigious names.

```
 // use namespace
 use Zend/Database/Adapter/Mysql as DbAdapter;
 $dbAdapter = new DbAdapter;

 // use naming convention    
 $dbAdapter = new Zend/Database/Adapter/Mysql;
```

When use namespace, if adapter is changed, your code would be not modified too many. All actions are only modify 'use' command.
Note that in upon example, the factory method pattern should not be cared.