# PHP namespacing benefits

Tags: php, namespaces

After doing some research about namespacing in PHP I'm trying to figure out what are the real benefits other than having library items grouped together and re-use of the same class name.

What I don't like about namespaces are these extra lines at the top of the file you're calling the classes from 'use core\whatever\class', which you don't have to do with the standard approach.

Also - something I couldn't find information about - what happens in the situation where we need to use two classes with the same name, but in the different folders, which contain the same method name? We would still have to call the namespace, but how would the code figure out which method from which class should be used?

I've just started with namespaces so excuse me if this question seem to sound very basic.

Also - how does it work with the static methods - things like Helper class for instance - do I also have to indicate that I need this namespace 'use core\whatever\Helper' ?

Comment: The answer is simple: to limit or eliminate ambiguity, to give a better structure to your code base. Think about it as one of the logical steps in having OOP concepts in PHP.

Comment: You don't need to use `use`. You can always call classes with their full-qualified name like `new \core\whatever\class`. However, you will miss the biggest benefit: readability. regarding your other questions (especially name conflicts), read http://php.net/language.namespaces

Comment: (1 of 2) I have the same question. I understand the benefit of being able to keep separate classes with identical names in different namespaces. But this is the only benefit I see and it comes at a big price. If I must write X USE statements at the beginning of a Php class file in order to create the various objects I need, how is this any different than using X require statements.

Comment: (2 of 2) Aside from the one obvious benefit, NAMESPACES seem like a step backward for me as a programmer. What would be very useful is is one could say "use abc" , where abc is a namespace comprised of several classes and all classes in this namespace could then be created without having specify each one in a separate use statement.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you have a large project with many classes, you'll eventually run into naming conflicts. You have a `db/mysql/adapter.php` and a `http/curl/adapter.php`. To deal with this without namespaces, you have to give your classes unique names like `Db_Mysql_Adapter` and `Http_Curl_Adapter`, and any time you refer to these classes you need to use their full name.

Namespaces allow you to name your classes `Db\Mysql\Adapter` and `Http\Curl\Adapter` and refer to them simply by `Adapter` in their local namespace, or `Mysql\Adapter` and `Curl\Adapter` respectively in other namespaces. This can save *a lot* of typing.

Just browse through the source of Zend Framework [version 1](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/1.11/) vs. [version 2](http://packages.zendframework.com/docs/latest/apidoc/index.html) to see the difference.

> what happens in the situation where we need to use two classes with the same name, but in the different folders, which contain the same method name? We would still have to call the namespace, but how would the code figure out which method from which class should be used?

If you're in namespace `Db\Mysql`, `Adapter::foo()` refers to `Db\Mysql\Adapter` and `\Http\Curl\Adapter::foo()` would refer to the other one. You can also alias the class at the top of your file, if you don't want to write out the whole name all the time:

```
namespace Db\Mysql;
use Http\Curl\Adapter as HAdapter;

Adapter::foo();  // Mysql adapter
HAdapter::foo(); // Http adapter, same as:
\Http\Curl\Adapter::foo();
```

Comment: Thanks deceze - this really helps a lot.

Answer (score 1):

> What I don't like about namespaces are these extra lines at the top of the file you're calling the classes from 'use core\whatever\class', which you don't have to do with the standard approach.

Namespaces group classes logically and avoid polluting the global scope. It also prevents you from making a big chunk of PHP code - code which may have parts needed in other places in your site. This makes it more reason to place it in another file for another part of the site to use. Don't Repeat Yourself (DRY), use in in many places but only code it once!

> what happens in the situation where we need to use two classes with the same name, but in the different folders, which contain the same method name? We would still have to call the namespace, but how would the code figure out which method from which class should be used?

Namespacing prevents these issues, using [aliases](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php). besides, having classes with the same name? unless they are the same name but different purpose or different subcategory, like `api.document.events` and `api.ajax.events`. Otherwise, it's bad program design.

Answer (score 1):

This answer focuses on @deceze 's answer.

His argument is that having two classes with different names is more complicated. Is it?

1.) His example code does not work because he never included the files. So it must look like this:

```
namespace Db\Mysql;
use Http\Curl\Adapter as HAdapter;

include('Db/Mysql/Adapter.php');
include('Http/Curl/Adapter.php');   

Adapter::foo();  // Mysql adapter
HAdapter::foo(); // Http adapter, same as:
\Http\Curl\Adapter::foo();
```

2.) You can not include the `adapter.php` files as long you do not add the namespace definition to this files, too:

```
<?php
// this is Db/Mysql/Adapter.php

namespace Db/Mysql;

class Adapter {
  static function foo() {
  }
}

?>
```

And now the non-namespace variant:

```
include('db/mysql/adapter.php');
include('http/curl/adapter.php');

MysqlAdapter::foo(); // Mysql adapter
CurlAdapter::foo(); // Http adapter
```

A `adapter.php` should look like this:

```
<?php
// this is Db/Mysql/Adapter.php

class MysqlAdapter {
  static function foo() {
  }
}

?>
```

Finally you need to edit as much files as before, adding more code as before. So this can not be the argument.

The only argument that could exist is that you avoid problems with conflicting [third party libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5393363/318765). But how many name conflicts did you have in the past? And how many libraries do you know that use namespaces so you do not need to edit all files?

The fact is, there is not benefit in the real world. This is something adopted from the C world that adds more confusing than benefits in my opinion.